# Run asynchronous while functions or multithread

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, php-7.2

I have a function that makes requests synchronized.
However, I need to loop for this function to be executed multiple times simultaneously.
What is the best way in PHP 7.2?

My code is not working as expected:

```
class AsyncOperation extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($threadId)
    {
        $this->threadId = $threadId;
    }
    public function run()
    {
        runMyFunction();
    }
}
$start = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $t[$i] = new AsyncOperation($i);
    $t[$i]->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about it(A succinct parallel concurrency API for PHP 7)-> https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel

Comment: Which of the two is recommended for high availability and thousands of simultaneous processes?

multi thread curl or Parallel?

Comment: Parallel is better suited to do that